# How to add QAction to QLineEdit in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making an application in pyqt5 in which I have to add QAction to QLineEdit. I have tried many times but failed.
[image: GitHub issues]
This is what I want
Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show what you've tried.  The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#addAction) seems fairly clear.

Comment: Those are for C but I am using python

Comment: Whatever I have tried is not working

Comment: **WHAT** did you try? "Whatever I tried" is completely pointless. The documentation is aimed for C++, not C, and, in any case, the functions are the same for Python in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very basic example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
# create line edit
line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
# create icon. Here I chose a random standard icon but you can create your own from one or more images.
icon = app.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowRight)
# add action to line edit
action = line_edit.addAction(icon, line_edit.TrailingPosition)
# connect action.triggered signal to a slot
action.triggered.connect(lambda: print('action triggered:', line_edit.text()))
# show line edit and start event loop
line_edit.show()
app.exec()
```